# Continuity of the largest eigenvalue with respect to length

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Let $k:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb R^+$ be a continuous function. For $a>0$, define $T_a$ acting on $L^2[0,a]$, by 
$$T_af(x) =  \int_0^a k(|x-y|)f(y)\,dy.$$
Clearly for each $a>0$, the operator $T_a$ is  compact (in fact Hilbert-Schmidt) and self-adjoint on $L^2[0,a]$. Denote the operator norm of $T_a$, by $\|T_a\|_{op}$.

$\textbf{Q1.}$Is the function $\phi:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$, defined by $\phi(a)=\|T_a\|_{op}$, continuous?

$\textbf{Q2.}$For $p\geq2$, is the function $\phi_p:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$, defined by $\phi_p(a)=\|T_a\|_{p}$,where $\|.\|_p$ stands for the Schatten $p-$norm, continuous?

$\textbf{Q3.}$Would the answer of the previous questions change if we consider $L^2-$ kernels instead of continuous ones?

Answer (score 2):

One possible trick is to put everything in terms of operators on $L^2(0,\infty)$.

Suppose (wlog) $k\in L^2(0,\infty)$. Then, I think, $||T_a||_{p,L^2(0,a)}=||M_aTM_a||_{p,L^2(0,\infty)}$ where $Tf(x):=\int_0^\infty k(|x-y|)f(y)\ dy$ and $M_af(x):=0$ for $x\ge a$ and $:= f(x)$ otherwise.

So you have $||T_a||_p-||T_b||_p=||M_aTM_a||_p-||M_bTM_b||_p$ whose absolute value is $\le ||M_aT(M_a-M_b)||_p+||(M_a-M_b)TM_b||_p$. As Schatten $p$-norm is (for $2\le p\le\infty$) bounded above by the Hilbert-Schmidt norm which is the $L^2(dx\times dy)$-norm of the kernel, the answer to questions 1 and 2 is *yes* (and *no, it doesn't change* to question 3).

Comment: After modifying those restriction operators (since the way they are right now, we would get a wrong composition),one will end up with inequalities, as opposed to equalities, for Schatten norms .That seems to be the catch.

Comment: The eigenfunctions of $T_a$ are exactly (the restrictions to $[0,a]$ of) those of $M_aTM_a$, if I'm not mistaken. Note that $M_aTM_af(x)=1_{[0,a]}(x)\int_0^\infty k(|x-y|)1_{[0,a]}f(y)\ dy=T_af(x)$ for $x<a$. So I think what I wrote is correct.